# Set up NTP server that does DST too?

Tags: time, ntp

I have several devices (routers and webcams) that do not support DST automatically.

But they do support NTP servers.

So I thought, would it be possible to set up my own NTP server that also adjusts automatically for DST and point my various devices and computers to it ?

As far as I read NTP is based on UTC so it does not have DST by default, but any hacks to do something like this?

Or is there a better alternative ?